# Unable to resolve Host - Windows Bash

Tags: windows, bash, sudo

I'm using Windows Bash and I'm getting the error `fox@FOX:/etc$ sudo true
sudo: unable to resolve host FOX`

I've seen people say I'm suppose to edit `etc/hosts`, but I don't know what to put in the file. Can someone tell me what I'm suppose to put to fix this?1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can fix this by adding an entry to your `/etc/hosts` for your machine's hostname.

If you want a one-liner, something like this will do it:

```
printf "\n127.0.0.1   $HOSTNAME\n" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

This will append a line to your `hosts` file that will resolve the current hostname to `127.0.0.1`.

When you run the command above you'll be prompted for the root password you set when the Windows Linux subsystem was installed. Also, since this command starts a shell for the root user just before it runs you'll actually see the `sudo: unable to resolve host WHATEVER` message one last time just before the change is made.

Alternatively, you run an editor (such as `nano`) as root and add the entry manually:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/491#issuecomment-231113792) to a workaround posted on the github issues tracker by user [benhillis](https://github.com/benhillis), stating:

> This is occurring because the /etc/hosts file does not contain your machine's name. To work around this you can remove /etc/hosts and it will be re-created after closing all open bash.exe windows and launching bash.exe

I can confirm this worked for me on Windows 10 Pro 64 build 1607.